# My login button isn't returning the required function, it is still returning the same login page

Tags: python, html, css, flask

this is my code

```py
from flask import Flask,request, render_template, redirect,session, url_for
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = "**********"
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = ""

db = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('login.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'email' in request.form and 'RegNum' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:    
            email = request.form['email']
            RegNum = request.form['RegNum']
            password = request.form['password']
            cursor = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM logininfo WHERE email= %s AND RegNum= %s AND password= %s", 
            (email, RegNum, password))
            info = cursor.fetchone()     
            if info['email'] == email and info["RegNum"] == RegNum and info['password'] == password:
            else:
                return "login unsuccessful, please register."

   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<h3 style="text-align:center">LOGIN FORM</h3>
<div>

<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-4">

<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-
describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">

<small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>

</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-4">
<label>Registration Number</label>
<input name="RegNum" type="number" min="1" max="20" class="form-control" id="inputId" 
placeholder="123409">
</div>

<div class="form-group">

<div class="col-3">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
<input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" 
placeholder="Password">
   
<button type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4">Login</button>

</div>
</div>

</form>

<form action="/new">
<small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted col-3">Don't have an account yet??.</small>
<a href="/signup" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4">Signup</a>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I can see with your code, assuming your indents are correct (a little tough to tell without it being in a code block), is that you're always returning the login.html template immediately. Because of this, you never get to that if check on the method. Remember that, since you're using a route, it's going to go through your lines of code in order, regardless of whether it's a GET or POST. If it sees a return first, it won't reach the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('login.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'email' in request.form and 'RegNum' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:    
            email = request.form['email']
            RegNum = request.form['RegNum']
            password = request.form['password']
            cursor = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM logininfo WHERE email= %s AND RegNum= %s AND password= %s", 
            (email, RegNum, password))
            info = cursor.fetchone()     
            if info['email'] == email and info["RegNum"] == RegNum and info['password'] == password:
        else:
            return "login unsuccessful, please register."
```

Answer (score 0):

You should render your template at the bottom of your `index` function:

```py
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit:
            # your logic for successful login
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            flash('login unsuccessful, please register')
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
    return render_template('index.html')
```

This ensures that the authentication process works first.